# Помогите запустить код на java

Tags: java, java-ee

Доброе время суток. Начел изучать java ee. И все примеры запускал через контейнер Weld используя библиотеку weld-se-shaded-3.1.3.Final.jar. Но последние примеры перестали запускаться.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



@Transactional
public class CustomerService {


    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;


    public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
    }



    public Customer findCustomerById(Long id) {
        return em.find(Customer.class, id);
    }



    @AroundInvoke
    private Object logMethod(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        logger.entering(ic.getTarget().toString(), ic.getMethod().getName());
        logger.severe(">>>" + ic.getTarget().toString() + " - " + ic.getMethod().getName());
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } finally {
            logger.exiting(ic.getTarget().toString(), ic.getMethod().getName());
            logger.severe("<<<" + ic.getTarget().toString() + " - " + ic.getMethod().getName());
        }
    }
}

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import java.util.Date;
import static javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE;


@Entity
public class Customer {


    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }


    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Подскажите как можно запустить этот код, желательно поподробнее. Файл beans присутствует. Может контейнер я в контейнере не правильно что вызываю или код вообще не рабочий подскажите кто не будь?

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


@WebServlet("/diExample1")
public class DependecyInjectionExample extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    CustomerService bookService36;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(bookService36.findCustomerById(22L));
    }
}
```

Comment: сюда скопировать главу из учебника?

Comment: Я не понял суть вашего вопроса. Тема называется СDI - перехватчики. Код был скопирован с гит хаба. Нужно запустить метод findCustomerById(Long id) или createCustomer.

Comment: Суть моего вопроса заключается в том, что ответ на ваш вопрос есть в каждом учебнике. Вы настолько ленивый, что не можете самостоятельно найти общедоступную информацию? Хотя судя по словам "нужно запустить метод" вы вообще не очень хорошо понимаете, что хотите сделать.

Comment: Я только начал, и вообще не понимаю, как оно должно работать. Через консоль или через какой- то браузер. Я пробовал через сервлет запустить у меня не получилось (. Я просто уже не знаю, что даже гуглить. 2 дня потерял на запуск этого приложение. Ткните носом в подробную инструкцию

Comment: Стоит начать с какой-нибудь хорошей книги для начинающих. Где по шагам будет объяснено что, зачем и почему делать

Comment: Всё разобрался контейнер не запускался из за логов, добавил injectionPoint запустился